# Use res.send and res.json together

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I want to create a file `config.js` containing JSON code.
Here is my code on app.js

```
app.get('/config.js', function(req, res) {
  var JSON = {
    "info": {
        "level1":  "Jeopardy Ready",
        "level2":  "Jeopardy Contender",
        "level3":  "Jeopardy Amateur",
        "level4":  "Jeopardy Newb",
        "level5":  "Stay in school, kid..." // no comma here
    }
  };
  res.format({'text/plain': function(){
    res.send(" var JSON = ");
  }
  });
 res.json(JSON);

});
```

I want to have result in config.js

```
var JSON = {
    "info": {
        "level1":  "Jeopardy Ready",
        "level2":  "Jeopardy Contender",
        "level3":  "Jeopardy Amateur",
        "level4":  "Jeopardy Newb",
        "level5":  "Stay in school, kid..." // no comma here
    }
    ]
  };
```

Any idea how to make it?
In my code I tried to use res.send and res.json together, but it couldn't works.

Comment: `text/plain` for jsonp?

Comment: @Bergi I think text/plain, because config.js will be accessed by jQuery in client side.

Comment: Accessed how? Parsed as JSON, executed as JSONP, or read and displayed as text?

Comment: @Bergi Parsed as JSON

Comment: Then why do you want to put `var JSON =` there at all? Just use `res.json(JSON)` and nothing else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simple

```
res.send(JSON.stringify(JSON_));
```

On client side

```
success: function(response){
  try{ 
    response = JSON.parse(response);
    // other logic 
  }
  catch(e){
     // your own logic, when json is not valid!
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
app.get('/config.js', function(req, res){
 var JSON_ = {
   "info": {
       "level1":  "Jeopardy Ready",
       "level2":  "Jeopardy Contender",
       "level3":  "Jeopardy Amateur",
       "level4":  "Jeopardy Newb",
       "level5":  "Stay in school, kid..." // no comma here
   }
 } 
 var JSONstr= JSON.stringify(JSON_);
 res.send("var JSON = " + JSONstr + ";");
});
```

You also have typos in your code example (square bracket on line 10)

Comment: I dont exactly get what you mean, but if it helps you can use res.json() instead of res.send()

Answer (score 0):

The methods are identical when an object or array is passed, but `res.json()` will also convert non-objects, such as null and undefined, which are not valid JSON.

Using `res.send`

```
var object = {
};
res.send(JSON.stringify(object));
```

The method ends up as a res.send() in the end:

```
 this.charset = this.charset || 'utf-8';
 this.get('Content-Type') || this.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
 return this.send(body);
```

Using `res.json`

```
res.json(object)
```